# How to start the scrollbar of a div at the bottom of the div even after resizing browser window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen many solutions such as:

```
$("#opening").prop({ scrollTop: $("#opening").prop("scrollHeight") });
```

or this:

```
$(window).load(function() {

      $("#opening").scrollTop($("#opening").height());

});
```

but all of these solutions only start the scrollbar at the bottom when the page first loads, and when I resize the browser window, the scrollbar starts at the top again. How do I make the scrollbar of a div start PERMANENTLY at the bottom, regardless of resizing of the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

On window resize, the positioning of the elements on page changes, hence, you will need to again execute your function to get the desired results. You can achieve the same by calling your function on window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

      $("#opening").scrollTop($("#opening").height());

});
```

Please note, in case of devices, you need to bind the same function to **orientationchange** event as well